# dy/dx when y is a function of x and z, f(x,z)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f(x,z)$ is a function of two variables x and z. Example would be $y=3x^2+4z^3$. If one tries to get $dy/dx$, what would be the result?

Comment: $y$ would be a function of $x,z$, so you might be thinking about $\partial y/\partial x$ maybe?

Comment: No. $dy/dx$. Not partial but total differentiation.

Comment: No.. So this is not possible? The answers below are illegal approaches? That's my question.

Comment: In case you are interested what you were referring to is formally known as the exterior derivative. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total derivative of $f$ shall be
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx}$$

This formula assumes that $z$ has some dependence on $x$. If there is constant dependence then $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$.

Comment: And what exactly is $dz/dx$ here?

Comment: The total derivative assumes that the variables may have dependence on each other. So $\frac{dz}{dx}(x)$ is the derivative of $z(x)$ the dependence of $z$ on $x$.

Comment: I see. So this is actually is a usual derivative $g'$ where $g(x)=f(x,z(x))$. The notation is at least obscure.

Comment: Yes that is what it is.